# Why does my module only list 10 nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes

I've been creating my very first module and have got some help here earlier. Now the issue is this: my module only list a maximum of ten (10) nodes.

The module is like a taxonomy term list, which shows nodes with a certain term. Althoug I have hundreds of nodes, and they each have the correct term, no term page shows more then 10 nodes.

If one node is removed, another one gets listed, so the error is somewhere else - but where?

Shortned down code:

```
function my_module_cmp($a, $b) {  
  $a = (array) $a;
  $b = (array) $b;

  return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$name = taxonomy_term_title($term);

drupal_set_title($name);

$terms = taxonomy_get_tree(10,0,1);

usort($terms, "my_module_cmp");

$counter = 0;
$result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid);

foreach($result as $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $alias = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$nid");
  $form['company_wrapper'][$nid]['title'] = array (
    '#markup' => '<div class="title"><a href="' . base_path() . $alias.'">' . $node->title . '</a></div>',
  );

  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Does changing the default 'Number of posts on the main page' (from Post Settings in D6) affect the result? What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7. I always forget to mention that.. I will try that.

Comment: Number of posts on main page, did not do the trick.

Comment: I would use Views for this. Even if you get this working, it would be a much better practice to not hard code this. Views will allow you to create the same list but also allow a non-coder to update this in the future.

Comment: I would've if it was possible in this case. The whole page is a big form for users to send messages to multiple receivers at once. So its not just a term page in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i can see, if `$limit == FALSE`, [`taxonomy_select_nodes()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes) just extends the [`PagerDefault`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/PagerDefault%3A%3Alimit/7), this class uses a limit of 10 unless otherwise specified, try changing your code so paging is disabled:

```
$result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, FALSE);
```

Comment: Yep this is it. PagerDefault has a default of 10.

Answer (score 3):

The [taxonomy_select_nodes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7) function has as default limit of unlimited, so if it's only returning 10 nodes, I would suspect that's all the nodes it was able to match against the provided taxonomy terms.

Note that this function will not return any unpublished nodes, nor return any nodes you do not have access to because of any node-access controlling modules.

Also note that `taxonomy_select_nodes()` *only* returns nodes that match $tid only - and not any of that term's children which might be what you are expecting.

Comment: But if I add a new node with a certain term, it wont show up. And if I remove one of the nodes in the list, another turns up, so there has to be a bug or limit somewhere.
All the nodes has been created automagically and have the same settings. And there shouldn't be any childterms, so that is as it should be too.